# Load modules dynamically with Require.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I am trying to load modules dynamically as described at the beginning of this post:

[Reference link](https://vickev.com/#!/article/grunt-the-perfect-tool-for-require-js)

Here is my `scripts/main.js`

```js
require.config({
  baseUrl: 'scripts',
  paths: {
    jquery: 'lib/jquery-2.0.3'
  },
  config: {
    'main': {
      modules: ['mod1', 'mod2', 'mod3']
    }
  }
});

require(function(require, exports, module) {
  console.log("Loading modules");
  require(module.config().modules);
});
```

When main.js gets loaded, code inside the outer require function never gets executed and "Loading modules" never gets printed to the console. Having read the AMD documentation at [This link](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html#sugar), I can't see what I am doing wrong. What is the proper way of dynamically loading modules defined externally in an array?

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

Here is what I have now:

```
// main.js
require.config({
  ...
  config: {
    'some_module': {
      modules: ['mod1']
    }
  }
});

require(['some_module'], function(some_module) {
});

// some_module.js
define(function(require, exports, module) {
  var mods = module.config().modules;

  var mod;
  for (var i=0; i < mods.length; i++) {
    mod = require(mods[i]);
    mod.fn_call();
  }
});
```

When I execute `require(module.config().modules)`, `mod1` indeed gets loaded. I am not sure how to use the return value of require to call a function returned by mod1, however.

With the code above, I get

```
Uncaught Error: Module name "mod1" has not been loaded yet for context: _
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded
```

How can I access the functions from the modules I am loading?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the **define** instruction:

```
define(function(require, exports, module) {
    console.log("Loading modules");
    require(module.config().modules);
});
```

By *config* property of RequireJS configuration you define configurations for each of your modules. Then, in module definition you may access that config, in your case to load dependencies.

In any case, I don't think you need to expose your application's main entry point as an AMD module, because it makes no sense. It should be like this:

```
// some_module.js (or path for some_module alias)
define(function(require, exports, module) {
    require(module.config().modules);
    ...
    return function () {};
});
```

```
// main.js
require.config({
  ...
  config: {
    'some_module': {
      modules: ['mod1', 'mod2', 'mod3']
    }
  }
});

require('some_module'); // loads some_module, mod1, mod2, mod3
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you loading your modules in this way? You're trying to make a async call inside a loop, basically you are rewriting your "mod" variable every time with another require even without the async call of require return something.

```
// some_module.js
define(function(require, exports, module) {
  var mods = module.config().modules;

  var mod;
  for (var i=0; i < mods.length; i++) {
    mod = require(mods[i]);//your loop doesn't will wait for it...
    mod.fn_call();
  }
});
```

Load your modules in this way and if you want to put some dependencies, you do that with config(http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config), i don't see any reasons to not do this...

```
define(['mod1', 'mod2', 'mod3'], function(mod1, mod2, mod3) {
         //do whatever you want with your modules
    });
```

Comment: As I described above, I would like to load modules dynamically from an array variable which I specify in the config property of Require.js configuration. Once loaded, I would like to call a function returned by each of those modules. Does that make sense? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: the way you're doing don't make any sense.

Comment: Could you please explain why is it not making sense? I have the same code that I would like to execute for each of those modules- create a button with an onClick attribute which triggers a function which is defined by each module. For that reason, I would like to have an array variable to which I can add as many modules as I need, whose functions are then used in a loop that creates a button for each one. Again, could you elaborate why this is not making sense and what is a better way to do this?

Comment: I already said why this don't make sense, neither in requirejs and neither in javascript works the way that you want it to work, and if you want to use these modules, you can use it in a module that call your modules like i did before and in the same way you did with array, with the module you can add or remove any modules that you want to call and put in any order of dependences(see config to do that).

Comment: @RodrigoFonseca - sounds like you need to read up on the open-closed principle. It is a common pattern to *register* a list of implementations via configuration of some type. Then, have an object that receives an *unknown* list of implementations (not hard coded as dependencies) - then execute them blindly - thus making the module open for extension, yet closed for modification. Requiring fixed params breaks this rule.