# Way to dynamically link to js scripts from client-side js?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to dynamically link javascript pages based on client-side javascript logic? For example in client-side html code I want something like:

```
<script>
    if(photoUpdate){
      import "./phtoLoader.js"       //Something like this?
    }
</script>
```

I am currently using server side to supply dynamic script imports and it feels very inefficient.

Comment: Check `require.js` : http://requirejs.org. But you need a strategy, based on module or route or something, on which you can manipulate async loading of scripts. Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21379023/load-modules-dynamically-with-require-js

Comment: That looks interesting. I'll check it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a dynamic script element and append to your document body.

```
function loadJS(file) {
    var jsElm = document.createElement("script");
    jsElm.type = "application/javascript";
    jsElm.src = file;
    document.body.appendChild(jsElm);
}
```